# How can I stop or unregister the GCMIntentService service?

Tags: android, service, push, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the GCMIntentService for receiving GCM messages. It all works as expected, but I allow the user to "quit" or stop the application, after which no new messages should be delivered to the device.

The question is, how can I stop the GCMIntentService from running? Because after I close everything down and call "finish" on my Activity, the GCMIntentService is still getting messages which sort of causes a NullRef.

And sure, I can do an if-statement to avoid the nullRef, but I want to stop the GCMIntentService altogether so its not longer running.

How can I do that?

Comment: Oh, please note that I do not want to unregister the device with GCM. THe user can start the app again, and the GCM regId remains the same.

Comment: Also note that I tried to stop the service using this code:
*stopService(new Intent(myOtherService.this, GCMIntentService.class));* but that did not work.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having exactly the same problem.

Comment: Nops, I havent a solution for it yet...

Comment: I tried few ways and the best solution was to just ignore the gcm message. I used a boolean value in shared preferences. I can post my code if you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about just ignoring the message you got from GCM? 
lets say you have a boolean determines the GCM status, when off you just ignore the incoming messages.

//
see http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar.html#unregister(android.content.Context)
`public static void unregister (Context context)` in `GCMRegistrar`

Comment: Yeah, as I noted in my question, "I can do an if-statement to avoid the nullRef, but I want to stop the GCMIntentService altogether so its not longer running" =)

Comment: Unregister what? The service? I cant really unregister a service, I can only unregister receivers etc... right?

Comment: Oh, I do not want to unregister the device. It should still be registred in GCM, but I no longer want the app to receive the updates. Therefore, I wanted to kill the service.

Comment: just to let you know, in iOS they handle this using flags (AFAIK)

Comment: I see. Well, maybe its the only way. As a side note: using iOS development as a reference is bad, because development for iOS is horrible, as far as I know... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If somebody is looking for the answer, my solution is:
In onDestroy disable my GCMListener class Intent-Filter:

```
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), MyGCMListenerClass.class), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, 0);
```

And in OnResume Re-enable:

```
getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), GCMListener.class), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

P.S.
All GCM messages will be ignored, so You will not receive them later.